# SQL 2005: how does a full backup affect log shipping?

Tags: sql-server

I'm planning to set up log shipping to a remote site for disaster recovery but I still want to take a nightly full backup so I can copy it to our backup tape and also use it to restore onto our reporting server. Can I do that without breaking the cycle of log backups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. You start the log shipping process from a restore of a full backup, and from then on you only need to restore transaction log backups. You can take as many diffs or full backups as you like and it doesn't affect the LSN and therefore does not interfere with the log shipping process as long as the logs are restored in order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL Backup overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477(SQL.90).aspx

FULL, and DIFFERENTIAL backups do not break the LSN log chain, so you are safe to take these backup anytime without affecting the log shipping